# Flutter forEach future

Tags: flutter

I am trying to take some data from firebase and than send that data to another request in firebase. The problem with that is that when i call my function, i get the print of the list which is at the end of the code empty but after that i get printed the results that should be in the list. I think this is due to the forEach function that it doesnt wait for it to finish. Here you have a photo of the code as well as the output.
https://gyazo.com/0867cb3cde904146dab12ccd907c6341

How can i do it so that the list comes out with the names after they print out

```
Future <List<Map < dynamic, dynamic >>> getData() async {
  List lists = [];
  DataSnapshot snapshot = await databaseReference.once();
  Map < dynamic, dynamic > values = snapshot.value;
  
  values.forEach((key, values) async {
      DataSnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Users/" + values["UID"].toString() + "/Name").once();
      lists.add(snapshot.value);
      print(snapshot.value);
   });
   print(lists);

}
```

Comment: *"How can i do it so that the list comes out with the names after they print out"* - use `Future.forEach`

Comment: https://gyazo.com/e0c089e3ef56daac3d3b0a0ee119a2fd how can i fix this?

Comment: use `Future.forEach` static method - `Future.forEch(elements, ...)`

Comment: https://gyazo.com/5be6ce529f314612e9c629f067f3b5a0 like this?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Hasilt/8d0584ac8ae2c8e5e147946cca0e0498

Comment: https://gyazo.com/2cfe6c6da2d4878f088e2c456fa68ecc something like this?

Comment: i dont understand whats the (key, values) at me

Comment: because i see in that example he made forEach(the list to cycle),(a variable to store in)

Comment: `await Future.forEach(values.values, (value) {...}) `

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! please put it as an answer so i can check it :)

Comment: your welcome, write a self answer then

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the problem you print the list before values.forEach((key, values)) is finished it works, you can do the right way to check if all element of values are processed and then print the list, for example

```
int count = values.length;

values.forEach((key, values) async {
      DataSnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Users/" + values["UID"].toString() + "/Name").once();
      lists.add(snapshot.value);
      print(snapshot.value);
      count--;
      if (count == 0) {
         print(lists);
      }
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use forEach, and make the inner function async, it won't wait for the whole forEach and that's why it print empty list.
You can use `for` cycle.

Answer (score 0):

you can use for loop to do this.

```
for(value in values)async
{
DataSnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Users/" + value["UID"].toString() + "/Name").once();
      lists.add(snapshot.value);
      print(snapshot.value);
}
```